# how to use a vector of keys to filter values from a map and produce a set using c++ ranges syntax

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl, range-v3, std-ranges

I am new to [Eric Niebler's ranges-v3 library](https://ericniebler.github.io/range-v3/) and I would like to solve the following simple problem:

I have a `std::map` containing the following:

```
std::map<std::string, int> map = {
    {"THIS", 1}, {"IS", 2}, {"A", 3}, {"TEST", 4}, {"WITH", 5}, {"MORE", 6}, {"KEYS", 7}
};
```

I have a `std::vector` containing a set of keys as follows:

```
std::vector<std::string> vec = {
    "THIS", "IS", "A", "TEST" 
};
```

How do I use the  library (ideally using the pipe composition syntax) to filter out pairs from the map containing the keys in the vector and transcode the resultant view to a `std::set<std::pair<std::string, int>>`.  Additionally to make the transcode interesting, make sure that the values in the map need to be odd.  In this case the range code should:

use these keys:

```
THIS,IS,A,TEST,
```

against this map

```
{A,3},{IS,2},{KEYS,7},{MORE,6},{TEST,4},{THIS,1},{WITH,5},
```

with an odd map value predicate - produce the following result as a different type of container `std::set`

```
{A,3},{THIS,1},
```

This should be relatively straightforward but I cannot figure out the new syntax.  Also any insight about eager vs lazy would be a plus to help me understand.

The following stripped down [**coliru**](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/259aafce42dc3559) example shows what I am looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Compared with traversing the entire `map`, it is more efficient to just traverse `vec` (generally small in size) and find the value corresponding to the key value from the `map` since the search operation of the map is logarithmic.

```
std::set<std::pair<std::string, int>> set;
std::ranges::copy(
  vec | std::views::transform([&map](auto& key) { return map.find(key); })
      | std::views::filter([&map](auto it) { return it != map.end() && 
                                                    it->second % 2 == 1; })
      | std::views::transform([](auto it) { return *it; }),
  std::inserter(set, set.begin()));
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/xxnGr3dEx)

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this:

```cpp
    std::map<std::string, int> map = {{"THIS", 1}, {"IS", 2},   {"A", 3},   {"TEST", 4},
                                      {"WITH", 5}, {"MORE", 6}, {"KEYS", 7}};

    std::vector<std::string> keys = {"THIS", "IS", "A", "TEST"};

    auto output = map | ranges::views::filter([&](auto &&pair) {
                      return std::find(keys.begin(), keys.end(), pair.first) != keys.end() && pair.second % 2 == 1;
                  });

    std::set<std::pair<std::string, int>> set(output.begin(), output.end());

    for (auto [key, value] : set) std::cout << key << " " << value << std::endl;
```

Here I have filtered the map with the vector and created a `range adaptor closure object`. Then I have created a set from output.

About the laziness, Look at this code:

```cpp
    std::map<std::string, int> map = {{"THIS", 1}, {"IS", 2},   {"A", 3},   {"TEST", 4},
                                      {"WITH", 5}, {"MORE", 6}, {"KEYS", 7}};

    std::vector<std::string> keys = {"THIS", "IS", "A", "TEST"};

    auto output = map | ranges::views::filter([&](auto &&pair) {
                      std::cout << "Seen" << std::endl;
                      return std::find(keys.begin(), keys.end(), pair.first) != keys.end() && pair.second % 2 == 1;
                  });

    std::cout << "I'm lazy!" << std::endl;

    std::set<std::pair<std::string, int>> set(output.begin(), output.end());

    for (auto [key, value] : set) std::cout << key << " " << value << std::endl;
```

I have added some prints. The output is:

```
I'm lazy!
Seen
Seen
Seen
Seen
Seen
Seen
Seen
A 3
THIS 1
```

Which shows that `output` is not evaluated until `output` is used to create the set.

Comment: I'm new to this so ... - If I understand it correctly, each time the filter lambda is called (which occurs for each NV pair in the map), we search all of the globally defined keys for a matching key string, and if there is a match we check that the value within the pair is odd.  This will happen for each NV pair in the map if I understand correctly. Is there a more efficient way?

Comment: The more efficient way would be going through the vector instead of the map which is the other answer.

Comment: do you think it would be possible to pre-sort the map and vector containers and use ranges set_intersection to be even more efficient.  Both containers (map and vector) in practice will be very large.  I recall using std::set_intersection in the past and I had to pre-sort the inputs for both containers (which were different types like here) but I cannot figure out how to use the ranges equivalent so I could have the expressiveness of functional code

Comment: @johnco3 The map is sorted by default. If both containers are sorted, Then the optimal algorithm to find common elements would take O(n + m). You are searching one in another which takes O (n * logm). If you are concerned with performance, I suggest writing a custom algorithm. Otherwise, this is enough.

Comment: thanks for the follow up, to that end I posted another question with a live coliru link http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7893faec83660442 - in this case I am using the std::set_intersecton instead of the corresponding one from ranges which is a bit more involved.  The issue here is trying to make a custom output type